# Android saving player scores

Tags: android, save

I want to show top players in my game. where can I save their scores? as I know I can do it using Google play services . any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at using Google Cloud Save service? Here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave

Comment: I dont know where to start

Comment: Just try to search on _Google_.You can easily understand how can you use that [_play service_](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using Google Cloud Save service? Here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave

Comment: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
what is app_id and APP_ID here?

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to define this in the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml). com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID is a constant, @string/app_id is defined somewhere in your strings.xml file, with a value obtained when you created the Client ID for your app (https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#b_create_a_client_id)